# fprintd error, no device detected

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I recently got a Dell Insprion 7000 2-in-1 laptop and I installed linux on it. I am trying to get the fingerprint reader to work. I checked and the reader is supported. USB ID 27c6:639c. But despite when I try to run fprintd-enroll, it just gives me an error.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What have you tried to make it work?